# how to get captcha ID (opt_widget_id)

Tags: javascript, captcha, webflow

I have integrate captcha v2 checkbox for two forms in one page, I validating captcha on client side before form submission, but when I am validating second captcha it is giving me value of first captcha in following code

var captchaValue=grecaptcha.getResponse().length;

I checked the documentation https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api, they have mentioned "opt_widget_id", I am not use how should I get captcha id. I am using webflow framework for my website which allow me to use captcha by just drag and drop so no code written for captcha.

Can anyone pleas help how I can I get captcha Id ("opt_widget_id")